# Account is removed in AD but User Profile still exist

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service, profile-sync

We are using SP 2013 On-Premises and User Profile Service (UPS) is setup to sync with our AD for more than a year. Most of the users created/deleted on AD will be added/deleted in the SharePoint UPS as expected.

However, we found some users:

1. Not existing in AD anymore (deleted) for half year but his profile still exist. We can search out this user in search center.
2. Some new users added in AD for half year but his profile is not created in SharePoint UPS.

The problem is the situation is not occurring to all but only SOME of AD accounts.

May I have your advice what could be the possible reason? So that I can make some test to verify it.

Comment: you said some users were missing from AD, so it looks like the sync is not happening correctly. can you redo a sync manually meaning re-importing. that should clear the problems. when was the last syn done and have you see the log entries. also make sure timer services are running properly.

Comment: Yes, SharePoint SYNC entries should be there with AD to have synch, then it will take all the data as expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can perform the following to resolve the issues:

1. Make sure User Profile Synchronization service is running
2. In the user profile service application make sure "`Profile Synchronization Status`" is not stuck in synchronizing state.
3. Start a full User Profile Synchronization
4. Re-add forest and make sure the password of the account used for synchronization isn't expired

Comment: What if the service stuck in synchronizing? I saw it occur before and restart the FIM sync service to recover. However the accounts/profiles in problem still there.

Comment: If it always get stuck in synchronizing state, you should first check the credentials of the account with which it is running. Second in farm services see if the User Profile Synchronization services is in "Started State"

Comment: It always fix the stuck after reset FIM sync service. Should I assume credential have no problem?

Comment: don't assume still problem is fixed. Make sure account have replicate AD permission!

Comment: I checked the FIM sync service was stopped. I don't have access to event log. I guess when server is rebooted something wrong with SQL connection. Also I found incremental ups sync missed some users. I have to use full-sync. Maybe because the service was not up for long time.

Comment: Glad it worked finally!

Answer (score 4):

based on your statement, it looks like the user profile sync is not happening properly.

follow the below troubleshooting steps:

1. Try doing a sync manually meaning re-importing. that should clear the problems.
2. Inspect the log entries
3. Make sure timer services and user profile sync services are running properly.
4. Also, additionally make sure the account used for connecting to AD is still having proper access at both SharePoint and AD.